# Restart Animation with Keyframes

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe, svg-animate

I can't for the life of me figure out how to restart my animation. Here's where I've gotten so far.
It's built with svg masking animations.

http://codepen.io/djmaller/pen/myrrbd

I want it to animate on as it currently is. But I want it to hold for a second or the last 10% of the animation, and then fade out before starting over. However I can't figure out how to prevent the animation from starting early. It's like it animates on fine but then it animates off in all random parts. So frustrating.

Does anyone have ideas here?
Am I building it wrong?
I believe the solution lies within the @keyframes in the CSS

HTML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<polygon id="clipmaskpath1" points="52.3,124.6 1.1,133.9 50.1,143.6"/>

<polygon id="clipmaskpath2" points="66.6,0.2 66.6,0.2 50.1,143.6 112.3,126.4 123.6,51.3"/>

<polygon id="clipmaskpath3" points="189.9,50.2 131.3,0.2 66.6,0.2 189.9,110.7 189.9,50.2"/>

<polygon id="clipmaskpath4" points="313.2,0.2 248.5,0.2 189.9,50.2 189.9,110.7"/>

<polygon id="clipmaskpath5" points="313.2,0.2 256.2,51.3 267.5,126.4 329.7,143.6"/>

<polygon id="clipmaskpath6" points="378.7,133.9 327.5,124.6 329.7,143.6"/>
```

```
<clipPath id="clipmaskA">
<use xlink:href="#clipmaskpath1" style="overflow:visible;"/>
</clipPath>

<clipPath id="clipmaskB">
<use xlink:href="#clipmaskpath2" style="overflow:visible;"/>
</clipPath>

<clipPath id="clipmaskC">
<use xlink:href="#clipmaskpath3" style="overflow:visible;"/>
</clipPath>

<clipPath id="clipmaskD">
<use xlink:href="#clipmaskpath4" style="overflow:visible;"/>
</clipPath>

<clipPath id="clipmaskE">
<use xlink:href="#clipmaskpath5" style="overflow:visible;"/>
</clipPath>

<clipPath id="clipmaskF">
<use xlink:href="#clipmaskpath6" style="overflow:visible;"/>
</clipPath>
```

```
<polygon id="A" style="clip-path:url(#clipmaskA)" points="52.3,124.6 1.1,133.9 50.1,143.6"/>

<polygon id="B" style="clip-path:url(#clipmaskB)" points="66.6,0.2 66.6,0.2 50.1,143.6 112.3,126.4 123.6,51.3"/>

<polygon id="C" style="clip-path:url(#clipmaskC)" points="189.9,50.2 131.3,0.2 66.6,0.2 189.9,110.7 189.9,50.2"/>

<polygon id="D" style="clip-path:url(#clipmaskD)" points="313.2,0.2 248.5,0.2 189.9,50.2 189.9,110.7"/>

<polygon id="E" style="clip-path:url(#clipmaskE)" points="313.2,0.2 256.2,51.3 267.5,126.4 329.7,143.6"/>

<polygon id="F" style="clip-path:url(#clipmaskF)" points="378.7,133.9 327.5,124.6 329.7,143.6"/>
```

And CSS

```
  svg {
  display:block;
  width:380px;
  height:144px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }


/*Shape Fills*/

#A, #D, #F {
  fill:#FFA95A;
  }

#B, #E {
  fill:#FF8300;
  }

#C {
  fill:#FFB571;
  }

/* Opacity Animation */

@keyframes fade{
  90%{opacity:1}
  100%{opacity:0}
}

.fade{
  animation:fade infinite running 2s ease-in-out;
}

/*Mask Animations*/

#svg-logo #clipmaskA {
animation: move-mask-1 infinite running 2s ease-in-out;
}

#svg-logo #clipmaskB {
animation: move-mask-2 infinite running 2s ease-in-out;
}

#svg-logo #clipmaskC {
animation: move-mask-3 infinite running 2s ease-in-out;
}

#svg-logo #clipmaskD {
animation: move-mask-4 infinite running 2s ease-in-out;
}

#svg-logo #clipmaskE {
animation: move-mask-5 infinite running 2s ease-in-out;
}

#svg-logo #clipmaskF {
animation: move-mask-6 infinite running 2s ease-in-out;
}

/* Mask Translations */

@keyframes move-mask-1 {
  0% {transform: translate(-99.99%,0%)}
  15% {transform: translate(0,0)}
}

@keyframes move-mask-2 {
  16% {transform: translate(-18%,99.99%)}
  30% {transform: translate(0,0)}
}

@keyframes move-mask-3 {
  31% {transform: translate(-99.99%,-99.99%)}
  45% {transform: translate(0,0)}
}

@keyframes move-mask-4 {
  46% {transform: translate(-99.99%,99.99%)}
  60% {transform: translate(0,0)}
}

@keyframes move-mask-5 {
  61% {transform: translate(-20%,-99.99%)}
  75% {transform: translate(0,0)}
}

@keyframes move-mask-6 {
  76% {transform: translate(-99.99%,0)}
  90% {transform: translate(0,0)}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that at the beginning of each @keyframe animation I needed to at a 0% translation that matches with where the mask is at the next step.

Before I had

```
@keyframes move-mask-2 {
  16% {transform: translate(-18%,99.99%)}
  30% {transform: translate(0,0)}
}
```

I fixed it by adding the line with 0%

```
@keyframes move-mask-2 {
  0%% {transform: translate(-18%,99.99%)}
  16% {transform: translate(-18%,99.99%)}
  30% {transform: translate(0,0)}
}
```